# Замена слов в строке на слова данные в массиве

Tags: php, алгоритм

Хочу заменить слова в строке `"My name is - %name%, username is - %username%"`, на слова данные в массиве `$arr`.

Вот код:

```
$elem = "My name is - %name%, username is - %username%";

    function get ($arr) {
        foreach ($arr as $var => $key) {
            $elem = str_replace($var, $key, $elem);
        }
    }

    get($arr = [
        "%name%" => "Alex",
        "%username%" => "alex_95"
    ]);

    echo $elem;
```

Но код неправильный. На выходе дает ту же самую строку, то есть без изменений

Где же ошибка?

Comment: в области видимости, не считая синтаксических

Comment: @teran Покажите пожалуста правильный код, чтоб я знал что вы имеете ввиду

Comment: я имею в виду вот это: http://php.net/manual/ru/language.variables.scope.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не забывайте про **global**;

```
$elem = "My name is - %name%, username is - %username%";

function get ($arr) {
    global $elem;

    foreach ($arr as $var => $key) {
        $elem = str_replace($var, $key, $elem);
    }
}

get($arr = [
    "%name%" => "Alex",
    "%username%" => "alex_95"
]);

echo $elem;
```

Comment: а объясните еще про параметры вызова `get( $arr = [....])` заодно

Comment: Про `global` лучше не вспоминать.